# changing config settings in Azure programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cloud, azure-worker-roles

I am writing a worker role that runs continuously, but I want to store the latest time it has run in a configuration setting that we use to timebox our queries so we run as few as possible.  Currently I am storing this date in Azure table storage, but I'm moving most of the other config settings to Azure so I started to wonder:

1. Is it possible to programmatically change config settings in Azure from a worker role?
2. Is this even a good idea, or should configuration settings be reserved for values that don't change very often?
3. If it isn't a good idea, what's the best place to store a value like this?  Keep it in table storage?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. At least with web.config, when you change a value, the website is restarted. I would store the last time it has run in a Sql Database or Azure Table.

Comment: Table storage is exactly what your after, its fast and reliably available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar requirement and used a Azure Storage Table to maintain task execution history. On each successive execution. Table doesn't even have to have any additional column as Timestamp property of the storage table entity tells the time at which the row was updated. In my implementation I just use PartitionKey, RowKey and Timestamp

Comment: I think that is the general consensus, for the reasons mentioned above as well.  I am going to continue to use Table Storage as it is already configured and seems to be exactly what I need.  Thanks @Amit!